# is there an R function to sample variables not cases?

Tags: r, simulation, sampling

Absolute R beginner here, but: I have k = 24 indicators for a latent construct. In fact, these indicators are interchangeable. To reduce the number of indicators for a scale measuring the latent construct I would like to randomly sample k=18 (or k=12 or k=6) indicators from the original k=24 indicators. Using random sampling with replacement, one might draw many samples (say, n = 1000)and then check if the statistics of interest (e.g. mean, variance, associations with external variables) change contingent on the number of k indicators. The problem is that I’d like to sample from the variables - not from the cases. I would hence be very grateful if someone might help me with e.g. R code to tackle this task? Best, E.

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried and sample data? Please edit the question with the code you tried and data in `dput' format.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. With the the built in mtcars dataset:
You could use `sample`: Here with k=6:

```
mtcars
dim(mtcars)

new_mtcars <- sample(mtcars, 6)
dim(new_mtcars)
```

```
 dim(mtcars)
[1] 32 11
> new_mtcars <- sample(mtcars, 6)
> dim(new_mtcars)
[1] 32  6
```

Comment: Yes, this is how it works - if it is done manually. I guess I should have been more clear in my request as I would like to draw a huge number of samples (say, 1000). Plus: the new samples would need to be saved in an efficient way....do you have any suggestions how to achieve this?